# How do I get the div section to override other styling code?

Tags: html, css

```
p, address 
{
    color: blue;
}

div.acolour 
{
    color: red;
}

<h1>Tutorial 1</h1>
<p><b>Ex 1.</b></p>
<p><b>Ex 2.</b></p>
<div class = "acolour">
<p><i>Sentence 1.</i></p>
<p><i>Sentence 2.</i></p>
<p><i>Sentence 3.</i></p>
</div>
```

The problem with this is since I made it so that all p tags are blue, the div section with p tags are also blue, but I want this section to be in red. How do I make it so that it is not overridden? Sorry if this was asked before.

Comment: This is a very basic question, and clearly shows that you haven't read about it before asking the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some thing like this will work :

```css
p,
address {
  color: blue;
}

div.acolour p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Tutorial 1</h1>
<p><b>Ex 1.</b></p>
<p><b>Ex 2.</b></p>
<div class="acolour">
  <p><i>Sentence 1.</i></p>
  <p><i>Sentence 2.</i></p>
  <p><i>Sentence 3.</i></p>
</div>
```